# set the context path of a web application in Tomcat 7.0

Tags: tomcat, context.xml

I have an application with WAR name like "`test< Version >.war`",every time the version changes. I need my context path to be "/test", I know that I can rename WAR file to test.war and deploy it. 
I added a file called `ROOT.xml` in `<catalina_home>/conf/Catalina/localhost/` and tried below configuration, it didn't wprk

```
<Context 
 docBase="test*.war" 
 path="/test" 
 reloadable="true" 
/>
```

Any suggestions to make this work?

Comment: My war has been deployed in webapps folder. Is it still necessary to provide full path ?But the my war file name changes every time that is version changes, I cannot hardcode the war name

Answer (score 0):

Do not set the `path` attribute in a `context.xml` file.

Instead, re-name the WAR file to be `appname.war`. In your case, it sounds like the WAR file has to contain version information, so you need to do things a little bit differently.

You were on the right track using `conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml`. This will set the context path for the application to "" (empty string, the "root" web application). If you want the application to be deployed under `/test`, then you need to re-name `ROOT.xml` to `test.xml`.

For the `docBase`, you need to have the correct WAR filename in there; no wildcards or anything like that are acceptable. You should use the fully-qualified path to your WAR file if possible. Also, the WAR file should not be in Tomcat's `webapps/` directory, or you'll end up deploying the application *twice* on to different context paths (`/test` and `/test-1.2.3.4`).